# Problem with Mean Value Theorem and Limit of Derivative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider the function $f(y)=\sin(y)$.
Then on the interval $[\sqrt x,x]$ by MVT $$\exists t\in(\sqrt x,x) \text{ s.t. } f'(t)=\frac {f(x)-f(\sqrt x) } {x-\sqrt x}. $$
Then by taking $x\to \infty \implies t\to \infty$
$$ \lim_{t \to \infty} f'(t) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac {f(x)-f(\sqrt x) } {x-\sqrt x} $$
But then this implies that $$ \lim_{t \to \infty} \cos(t) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac {\sin(x)-\sin(\sqrt x) } {x-\sqrt x} = 0 $$
Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Even simpler: $\displaystyle \lim_{t \to \infty} \cos(t) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac {\sin(x+2\pi)-\sin(x) } {2 \pi} = 0$ since $\sin(x+2\pi)=\sin(x)$. Can you spot the error now?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3493057/42969.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because is $t_{x}$ actually. We have that for each $x$ there exist some $t_{x} \in (\sqrt{x},x)$ such that $cos(t_{x}) = \frac{\sin(x)-\sin(\sqrt{x})}{x-\sqrt{x}}$

May be $t_{x} = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2m_{x}\pi$ for all $x$, with $m_{x}\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $m_{x} \to \infty$ when $x\to \infty$.

The point is, $cos(t_{x}) \to 0$ when $x\to \infty$ not implies that $cos(t) \to 0$ when $t \to \infty$